# How to access database which is in skydrive and its contents?

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have a database in my OneDrive account. Now I want to access that database in my Window 8 app. I want to use the contents of database in my app. But don't know how it will accessible. I want to bind the contents of that database in a list and want to show them in my Window 8 app.

I have successfully login in my OneDrive account. But don't know how to access the database contents in a list.

Following is the code through which I am login in my OneDrive account, but now what I should do to get the database content in a list?

```
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "wl.signin", "wl.basic", "wl.skydrive_update" });
if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
{
    App.MainViewModel.IsUploaded = true;
    App.MainViewModel.IsVisible = Visibility.Visible;
    App.Session = authResult.Session;
    LoadData();
}
```

Can anyone help me, how I can do it ?

Comment: There's no database server running in OneDrive. So you need the database logic locally. What kind of database is it? What is the file size? What options do you have for editing files online in OneDrive?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will work that way. There isn't a **SGBD** running in *OneDrive* so you must download it entirely in your app.

The closest think you can do is treat things as files and store the data as JSON. But you can't easily query it with SQL instructions.